# OpenSSH Two Phase Login

Tags: ssh, passwords, openssh, phase, passphrase

I would like it if when I use OpenSSH like so:

```
ssh user@host
```

that it asks for a passphrase

```
Please enter Passphrase:
```

then asks for the password

```
Please enter Password:
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A passphrase, in the normal SSH sense of the word, will decrypt your private key, which obviates the need for a password. Why do you want to ask for both?

Answer (score 2):

i think you can configure pam to do so. Pam mean pluggable authentication modules which provide login prompt for you, ssh is configured to use UsePam.

you should configure your login with multiple authentication modules so it ask your password mutiple times.